# Model's property in javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have the following `javascript` code:

```
$(window).bind("scheduleComplete", (function (event, params) {

    var hallCount = "@Model.EventSchedules.Actual().Hall.Levels.Count";
    var level; 
    //other code

}));
```

I want to bind only when `if` statement is `true`:

```
if("@Model.EventSchedules.Count" !== "0")
{
 $(window).bind("scheduleComplete", (function (event, params) {

        var hallCount = "@Model.EventSchedules.Actual().Hall.Levels.Count";
        var level; 
        //other code

    }));
}
```

`Model.EventSchedules.Count` equals `0`, but code inside it runs anyway.
Where is a problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you an alternative approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.EventSchedules.Actual().Hall.Levels.Count));
    if(count > 0) {
        $(window).bind("scheduleComplete", (function (event, params) {
            //other code
        }));
    }
</script>
```

will render as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 5;
    if(count > 0) {
        $(window).bind("scheduleComplete", (function (event, params) {
            //other code
        }));
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the !== operator which will need an exact match. If you use != it will use type coercion which will probably make it work. If it does, you know that there is a typing issue. Maybe try without the quotes and work from there.

You could also do the check at the server side and only output the JS if you need it.